# Calculating summary for rows and columns in pentaho report designer

Tags: mysql, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-report-designer

I am creating a report with some data like below:

```
      1/1  1/2  1/3  1/4 
A    2    1    2    1
B    4    5    6    8
```

For the above data i would like to summarize each column and each row totals like below.

```
    1/1  1/2  1/3  1/4 
A    2    1    2    1    --> 6(addition of all values)

B    4    5    6    8    --> 23

     6 6 8 9   29
```

Please suggest how to achieve this using pentaho report designer.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know more of your data but it's a classic sum in mysql :

```
SELECT column, SUM(column) FROM table
GROUP BY column
```